# Search PowerPoint presentations for text

Tags: search, microsoft-powerpoint, file-search

I have a large collection of PowerPoint presentations in the XML/.pptx format. I would like to find all presentations containing a particular string of text. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using Windows Search?

Comment: @Twisty Yes, it didn't find any of the files I was looking for -- it seemed to search only the filenames. That's why I came here.

Comment: please edit that into your question

Answer (score 0):

If you have the files in .xml format you can use [AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/). You can search for keywords in multiple file formats. It shows you the files where it finds the keyword, the line where the keywords are located and a preview.

[image]

Comment: The files are in pptx format, so there are xml files inside them but I don't know if AstroGrep would be able to decompress them.